# Do I need to spend money on Create Undead every 24 hours?

Tags: dnd-5e, spell-components

So the PHB for Create Undead says the materials required to cast it are

> one clay pot filled with grave dirt, one clay pot filled with brackish water, and one 150 gp black onyx stone for each corpse

it also says that my control over the ghouls lasts for 24 hours and that I must re-cast the spell every 24 hours to reassert control. Otherwise, I assume, the ghouls are acting on their own rather than destroyed. This leads me to think that I may not need to use another onyx stone to re-cast it because it can be inferred that that component is for willing a corpse to life rather than asserting control over it.

Do I need to burn 450 gp worth of onyx every 24 hours to have 3 ghouls under my control? It seems rather expensive. Looking for RAW, but also any alternatives you may have used in your sessions.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Unless specifically stated, material components are not consumed by a spell.

Create Undead doesn't say that the onyx stones are consumed so no, you don't need to "burn" 450 gp each time you (re)cast the spell but you do still need to provide the components for each recasting.

The rules for components can be found on page 203 of the PHB.

Comment: That's very interesting! Was it the case in 3.5e too?

Comment: No; in 3.5e, any material components with a stated cost were consumed by the spell. In 5e they've stated that materials are only consumed if explicitly stated, so the cost for non-consumed components is basically a barrier to entry on being able to cast it originally. Once you've got the parts, you can cast it as long as you have them.

Comment: To clarify what anaximander said, 3.5rd edition had both "material" and "focus" components, the difference between them being that material components were consumed as part of the spellcasting process but focus components stuck around and could be used again. 5e goes back to 2e's habit of calling both kinds of component "material."